# JQuery tablesorter - Keeping grouped subheaders together, but still sorted

Tags: javascript, jquery, tablesorter

I'm not really a Javascript programmer, so I'm struggling with this! I'm using the [tablesorter](http://tablesorter.com/docs/) plugin along with the [Tablegroup](http://www.pengoworks.com/workshop/jquery/tablesorter/tablesorter.htm) plugin, which work very nicely to group the table rows by a parent, and then sort the parents.

My problem is though, that I'd also like the child rows to be sorted *whilst within the parent group*

I've done my best to get this working but I'm afraid I've hit a wall. Can anyone suggest a new starter for 10?

The example below is working fine - There are 2x groups here:

1. Nordics (Norway and Denmark)
2. DACH (Germany and Austria)

If I click on the header row, the groups are sorted, but the child rows within the group are not sorted.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".tablesorter")
                .tablesorter({
                // set default sort column
                sortList: [[0,0]],
                // don't sort by first column
                headers: {0: {sorter: false}}
                , onRenderHeader: function (){
                    this.wrapInner("<span></span>");
                }
                , debug: true
            })
        }); 
</script>
<table id="results-header" class="grid tablesorter table-header" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
  <thead>
    <tr class="title">
      <th class="countries">&nbsp;</th>
      <th>% market share</th>
      <th>% increase in mkt share</th>
      <th>Target achieved</th>
      <th>% targets</th>
      <th>% sales inc. M-o-M</th>
      <th>% sales inc. M-o-M for country</th>
      <th>% training</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="Nord" class="collapsible parent parent-even collapsed">
      <td class="countries">Nordics</td>
      <td>39.5</td>
      <td>49</td>
      <td>69.8</td>
      <td>51.8</td>
      <td>43</td>
      <td>42.5</td>
      <td>38</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="row-Norway" class="expand-child child child-Nord">
      <td class="countries">Norway</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>45</td>
      <td>101</td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>20</td>
      <td>40</td>
      <td>30</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="row-Denmark" class="expand-child child child-Nord">
      <td class="countries">Denmark</td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>20</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>40</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>25</td>
      <td>8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="DACH" class="collapsible parent parent-odd collapsed">
      <td class="countries">DACH</td>
      <td>77</td>
      <td>61</td>
      <td>43</td>
      <td>98</td>
      <td>65</td>
      <td>92.5</td>
      <td>59.5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="row-Germany" class="expand-child child child-DACH">
      <td class="countries">Germany</td>
      <td>56</td>
      <td>24</td>
      <td>84</td>
      <td>98</td>
      <td>32</td>
      <td>87</td>
      <td>21</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="row-Austria" class="expand-child child child-DACH">
      <td class="countries">Austria</td>
      <td>98</td>
      <td>98</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>98</td>
      <td>98</td>
      <td>98</td>
      <td>98</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Without trying this out it looks like you only use the tablesorter as your call looks like

```
$(".tablesorter").tablesorter({...})
```

If you are using tableGroup shouldn't there be some calls like this one around?

```
$(...).tableGroup({...})
```

On the homepage of tableGroup the code looks like this

```
$('table').tableSorter({...}).sortStop(function (e, col) {
    $(this).tableUnGroup();
    ...
        $(this).tableGroup({...});
    ...
});
```

Comment: sorry, I linked the wrong mod! The RIGHT mod uses it's own tablesorter-mod.js and so you do just call tablesorter(), it just does it's own thing.